# How many days after registering a baker can you delegate to another baker to make sure you don't miss the rewards from the grace period?

Tags: solo-baking

I'm just wondering because on tezblocks it hasn't registered me yet, and I'm thinking about transfering the tezzies to another account and registering them to a baker for the 20?  days it take for the baker get baking rights

Answer (score 3):

From a Tezos protocol perspective the answer is you don't have to wait at all and there is no grace period.

This is a common misunderstanding, but you need to think in cycles which are made up of 4096 blocks. Every cycle there are 16 snapshots taken, eventually one of these snapshots will be randomly selected to represent the "delegation and staking balances" for that cycle. That snapshot will be used to generate rights which will be baked 7 cycles later but you do not have to wait to make any changes to your delegate or balance.

*Once you are sure your delegation has been included in the snapshot for a given cycle you are free to either transfer your tokens or change your accounts delegate (baker) without having any impact on the previous snapshot; most bakers will give you credit for that previous snapshot once they have baked 7 cycles later regardless of what you have done in between.*

But the payments made to you by a baker for your delegation is part of an offchain agreement you have with your baker. You need to contact the baker to determine any details regarding their policy.

Comment: So I registered my baker on 11/10/2019, however tzstats isn't showing me registered as a baker yet.  Will it start showing after 7 cycles?